# Reading XML and creating a frequency count of elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, optimization, datatable, xmlreader

I have an XML file in this format (but only much bigger) :

```
<customer>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>24</age>
    <gender>M</gender>
</customer>
<customer>
    <name>Keith</name>
    <age></age>         <!--blank value-->
    <gender>M</gender>
</customer>
<customer>
    <name>Jenny</name>
    <age>21</age>
    <gender>F</gender>
</customer>
<customer>
    <name>John</name>   
    <age>24</age>       <!--blank value-->
    <gender>M</gender>  <!--blank value-->
</customer>
```

I want to generate a DataTable which will be in this format :

> **Element Name**   **Value**    **Frequency** 
>  name       filled     4
> name       blank    0
> age          filled     2
> age       blank    2
> gender        filled    3
> gender        blank    1

Currently I am completing this task in 2 parts, first creating a DataTable structure as above and setting all the frequencies to 0 as default. And then reading the XML using [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx), and increasing the count of the frequency everytime XmlReader finds a child element.
My problem is that the second function that I use for adding the actual count is taking too long for very big Xml files with many customers having many attributes. How can I improve the efficiency of this function?
 My code :

```
static void AddCount(DataTable dt)
{
     int count;
     using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Usr\sample.xml"))
     {
         while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    string eleName = reader.Name;
                    DataRow[] foundElements = dt.Select("ElementName = '" + eleName + "'");  
                    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    {
                       count = int.Parse(foundElements.ElementAt(0)["Frequency"].ToString());  
                       foundElements.ElementAt(0).SetField("Frequency", count + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       count = int.Parse(foundElements.ElementAt(0)["Frequency"].ToString());  
                       foundElements.ElementAt(0).SetField("Frequency", count + 1);
                    }
                }
            }   
       }   
  }
```

I am also ready to change the XmlReader class for any other more efficient class for this task. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that querying in the DataTable using the Select operation was very expensive and that was making my function very slow.

Instead of that, used a `Dictionary<string, ValueFrequencyModel>` and queried on that to fill the dictionary with the count, and after completing that, converted the `Dictionary<string, ValueFrequencyModel>` into a DataTable.

This saved loads of time for me and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
    using (XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\aks\Desktop\sample.xml"))
        {
            var customers = xdoc.Descendants("customer");
            var totalNodes = customers.Count();

            var filledNames = customers.Descendants("name").Where(x => x.Value != string.Empty).Count();
            var filledAges = customers.Descendants("age").Where(x => x.Value != string.Empty).Count();
            var filledGenders = customers.Descendants("gender").Where(x => x.Value != string.Empty).Count();

            var unfilledNames = totalNodes - filledNames;
            var unfilledAges = totalNodes - filledAges;
            var unfilledGenders = totalNodes - filledGenders;
        }
```

Comment: I thought of using XDocument, but the problem with this is that it loads the whole XML file on memory, and as I said, I am dealing with very large XML files so I wouldn't prefer to do that.
[Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096564/xmltextreader-vs-xdocument).

Although thanks for this help... will use this as my last option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic, currently I have only taken only one attribute here ie *Name*

```
        XDocument xl = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Usr\sample.xml");
        var customers = xl.Descendants("Customer");
        var customerCount = customers.Count();
        var filledCustomers = customers.Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value != string.Empty).Count();
        var nonfilledCustomers = customerCount - filledCustomers;
```

Comment: I thought of using XDocument, but the problem with this is that it loads the whole XML file on memory, and as I said, I am dealing with very large XML files so I wouldn't prefer to do that.
[Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096564/xmltextreader-vs-xdocument).

Although thanks for this help... will use this as my last option.