# Reading in XML in C# - Grab specific Element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm reading in some XML and displaying it in a DataGridView which works great.

However, my life would be 10x easier if I could grab specific Elements and read their content. (Im using XmlReader)

Additionally, is there a simple way to loop through an element? I need to grab the count and then loop through each "Facility" but I cant seem to get this working properly. Adding another "While(read)" in wasnt a great solution.

I would prefer not to switch to another reader at this time, I'm in to deep with this one at the moment.

**XML Data:**

```
    <data>
    <count>2</count>
    <facility>
        <typeId>1</typeId>
        <type>Beds</type>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
        <description>null</description>
    </facility>
    <facility>
        <typeId>2</typeId>
        <type>EDBeds</type>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
        <description>null</description>
    </facility>
</data>
```

**Code:**

```
while (xr.Read())
{
    if (xr.Name.Equals("count"))
    {
        valueName.Text = "We currently have " + xr.ReadElementContentAsString() + " facilities open.";
    }
    while (xr.ReadToFollowing("facility"))
    {
        //Add a new row for data if we are at a new Facility element
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "facility")
        {
            row = generalData.Rows.Add();
            col = 0;
        }
        //Loop through current facility Element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096564/xmltextreader-vs-xdocument) why you should prefer `XDocument` over `XmlReader`. As it states the API for XDocument is alot easier and supports 'LINQ To XML'. XmlReader is has become obsolete since it's out dated and contains bugs.

```
var xml = @"
<data>
    <count>2</count>
    <facility>
        <typeId>1</typeId>
        <type>Beds</type>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
        <description>null</description>
    </facility>
    <facility>
        <typeId>2</typeId>
        <type>EDBeds</type>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
        <description>null</description>
    </facility>
</data>";

var xDocument = XDocument.Load( new StringReader( xml ) );
var facilityElements = xDocument.Descendants().Where( x => x.Name == "facility" );

// Count the elements
var count = facilityElements.Count();

foreach ( var facilityElement in facilityElements )
{
    // Handle elements
}

// Adds an facility element
var facility = new XElement( "facility" );
var typeId = new XElement( "typeId" );
typeId.SetValue(3);
facility.Add( typeId );
xDocument.Element( "data" ).Add( facility );
```

Comment: I totally agree, If anyone see's this question I would highly recommend using a different reader. XmlReader was a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

For the given XML data, we don't need to loop through every 'facility' elements to bind it's data on DataGridView.

Instead, we could follow below easy steps,

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xr);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["facility"];
```

--SJ

Comment: Fantastic! This will do

Answer (score 0):

Jumped the gun, using "ReadSubTree()" works well for this:

```
                    XmlReader inner = xr.ReadSubtree();
                    while (inner.Read())
                    {
                        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        {
                             //Do stuff
                        }
                    }
```